# Setting 10 products per page in magento

Tags: magento

How to 10 products per page in magento ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalog.xml
and go to the line number 85

```
and find catalog/product_list_toolbar just modify ur xml according to ur need.
```

Answer (score 9):

It's actually even easier than modifying XML. There's an admin panel setting for this under Catalog > Frontend > "Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values". Change this value and your toolbar options will be updated.

Comment: If you can't find the admin panel for this, it's under System > Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly setting from magento admin panel 
goto Systam > CATALOG > catalog > Frontend  and set the grid list of product [image]